# Sequelize create index on JSONB attribute

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

How do I create an index using sequelize's syntax for a JSONB field in postgres?

The index I want to create in SQL would be:

```
CREATE INDEX people ON people (cast(people.data->>'id' AS bigint));
```

How do achieve this with the sequelize syntax?
I've searched the docs and googled for examples but come up blank.

Comment: Instead of field name, you can provide `Sequelize.fn` in your index definition. Maybe you could use something like `Sequelize.fn("CAST", Sequelize.col("data"))`. I don't know its syntax so I just leave it as possible hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to your Model Definition.

I am giving a basic example below:

```js
const Test = sequelize.define(
    'People',
    {
        data: {
            type: DataTypes.JSONB,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'data',
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'people',
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
        indexes: [{
            name: 'people_data_id',
            fields: [Sequelize.literal("((\"data\"->>'id')::int)")]
        }]
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a more elegant way to do this, ended up using an afterSync hook:

```
        afterSync(options, done) {
            co(function* () {
                yield sequelize.query(
                    'CREATE INDEX people ON people (cast(people.data->>\'id\' AS bigint));'
                );
            })
            .then(() => done())
            .catch(err => done(err))
        }
```